# Hosting a NodeJS application in different location is not working with Nginx

Tags: 16.04, nginx, nodejs

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name  mydomain.com;
    location /sublocation/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Here I have used two different locations for handling requests in the server for  different applications but still, I get 404 error while accessing http://mydomain.com/sublocation/

But I can access using http://mydomain.com:8090/

I can't get what is the issue. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the path may still have `/sublocation` in the query.

## simple for nginx, complex for express

Try:

```
    location /sublocation {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3040/sublocation;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

But inside your express aplication you must put `/sublocation` as root!
You can do something like:

```
    var mainApp = express();
    mainApp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true, limit: '50mb'}));
    //...
    var app = express(); // your current app
    mainApp.use('/sublocation',be.app); // here is the magic
    //rest of your app
```